# Storage elements from binary tree in array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, recursion, binary-tree

I want to store my elements from my binary tree into an array but have no idea how to do it...
I already have a count method for the size of my array, now i need to store my int elements into an array

```
public int countNode() {
    if (this.root == null) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        int count = 1;
        count += root.l.countNode();
        count += root.r.countNode();
        return count;
    }
}

public int[] arrayStorage() {
    int[] a = new int[countNode()];


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add it to array by level order traversing the tree using queue.

The main reason we don't follow this approach for a binary tree is that this wastes a lot of space in array when the tree isn't complete unlike a heap.